# print 0 if the word is palindrome and -1 if it is not(without conditions and loops)

Tags: python-3.x, palindrome

I need to check whether the string is a palindrome or not (without conditions and loops) and print '0' if the string is palindrome and '-1' if it is not a palindrome.

I am unsure what to do after reversing the string by `string[::-1]`.
How to compare both strings to check palindrome without any loops or conditions?

(PS. I am not supposed to use any loops or conditions(including if,else))

Comment: So you're not allowed to use an `if` statement?

Comment: `string == string[::-1]`? But that will still require an `if` for to return the right value.

Comment: You can do it in a oneliner without condition and loops !`[-1,0][string==string[::-1]]` I am not sure this is what you need. Can you clarify what you cannot use ?

Comment: It worked! @BlueSheepToken but can you explain in detail about '[-1,0]' for my own knowledge. I am unaware of this.

Comment: @Blue that is wicked

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) under "Asking about homework"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you asked for an explanation, I am writing an answer for you.

But be aware, except in very particular cases (such as golf code), I **strongly** discourage this practice.

If you want to not use `if` `else`, you could simply "trick it", using the fact that `True` converts to `1` implicitly and `False` to `0` in some cases.

You can use it in two ways :

## Solution 1

Access elements in an array converts the `bool` to `int`, let's construct an array with the right element at the right index :

```
[-1,0][string==string[::-1]]
```

If `string==string[::-1]` evaluates to `True` (this is a palyndrome) then the second element of the array will be accessed. Otherwise, the first one.

## Solution 2

Another solution, is to find a "function" which converts `1` to `0`, and `0` to `-1`. The easy one is `f(x) = x - 1`

Which leads to :

```
(string == string[::-1]) - 1
```

Keep in mind, my comment was more a joke than a real solution, you should probably not use it in the real world !

PS: By "no conditions", I suspect it to mean "without comparing letters one by one", but I do think a

```
if string == string[::-1]:
    print(0)
else:
    print(-1)
```

is totally acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Just the comparison doesn't require any loops or conditions:

```
string == string[::-1]
```

This will return `True` or `False`.

Now for how to get that to `0` or `-1`, here are some hints:

- You can cast `bool` to `int`: `True` → 0, `False` → 1
- Negative zero is zero

I did figure out a full solution, but since this seems like homework, I don't want to just *give* it to you. I hope the hints encourage you to figure it out yourself.

---

For what it's worth, if you were allowed to use conditions, I would recommend a ternary `if` statement:

```
-1 if string == string[::-1] else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :

```
print(str_a == str_a[::-1] and '0' or '-1')
```

Comment: Note this works in this case, but using `and`-`or` in place of `if`-`else` is bad practice. For example if you switch use ints instead of strings thinking it will be the same, it will always print -1 since 0 is falsy.